# Can I log in from an Android phone without using the phone's google account?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've got a pokemon go game started with my google account and have been playing with my son.  My wife wants to put the game on her phone too so she can play with him during the week.  But on her phone (Google Android), it seems to force login with her own google account set up on her phone.

On mine (iOS), after hitting Sign In, it actually gives me a login box to enter email, and then password.  On hers, it seems to be an automatic login and goes immediately to the new game setup.  We can't find any option to say which account I want to log in with.

Any options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android phones do that when they only have 1 google account in them. If you have multiple accounts on a phone, a screen will pop up asking which account to login with.
[image]

So to solve this problem, just add any other google account from here:-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since she's using an Android phone, I believe that she would have to log out of her google account on the entire phone in order to prevent an auto-login for the game. Most apps on Android phones have this behavior. But logging out of her google account on her phone would cause her to have to log into it on every app she uses every single time she opens them, which may not be worth the trouble. I can't make that determination, that would have to be something she decided.